# Getting attributes of source element in JQuery UI Context Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to get the data-id attribute of the source element when the context menu is activated. How can i access the source element? Here is what Ive done so far:

```
 $(".action").contextmenu({
        menu: [
            {title: "View", cmd: "view", uiIcon:'ui-icon-zoomin' },
            {title: "Edit", cmd: "edit", uiIcon:'ui-icon-pencil'},
            {title: "Login History", cmd: "history", uiIcon:'ui-icon-clock'},
            {title: "----"},
            {title: "Deactivate", cmd: "deactivate", uiIcon:'ui-icon-closethick'},
            {title: "Switch", cmd: "switch", uiIcon:'ui-icon-newwin'},
        ],
        select: function(event, ui) {
            //get the 'data-id' attribute here.          
        }
    });
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try `$(this).data('id')` or I guess `ui` contains the complete information

Comment: Strange, `this` is usually accessible. Try doing `alert(this.nodeName)` and see if it alerts anything. If it does, the `this` object is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code within select function:

```
$(event.target).data('id')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will try next time. but I am making these posts from my mobile so I haven't added code block

Comment: i was able to solve the problem with the following code:

event.target.id